# Running python script when creating AWS EC2 new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new at AWS and kind of having a rough time here.

I have a script in Python running on a Windows EC2, which is a SQS subscriber. When the script gets a new message from the SQS, it executes a '.exe' file on the machine in order to run some calculations, getting the result and uploading it on a S3.

Right now we have to run it manually, but we want the subscriber to be running when the instance is starting or rebooting or a new instance is created.

I have tried to use the EC2 user data for that (with the persist tag), but nothing is happeging, the script it is not running at all and I can't see any log under the ' C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log' path.

The user data I have used is the one from the AWS documentation, once this is working I will trying with the other one:

```
<script>
echo Current date and time >> %SystemRoot%\Temp\test.log
echo %DATE% %TIME% >> %SystemRoot%\Temp\test.log
</script>
<persist>true</persist>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, this might not be the best approach in order to solve this problem. Any idea is welcome.

Thanks in advance.